# Trying to understand nbits value from stratum protocol

Tags: bitcoin, dogecoin-api

I'm looking at the [stratum protocol](http://mining.bitcoin.cz/stratum-mining) and I'm having a problem with the nbits value of the mining.notify method. I have trouble calculating it, I assume it's the currency difficulty.

I pull a notify from a dogecoin pool and it returned 1b3cc366 and at the time the difficulty was 1078.52975077.

I'm assuming here that 1b3cc366 should give me 1078.52975077 when converted. But I can't seem to do the conversion right.

I've looked [here](http://op-co.de/tmp/0001-Display-network-difficulty-on-new-block.patch), [here](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoin-mining-hard-way-algorithms.html) and also tried the .NET function [BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Can someone help me understand what the nbits value signify?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right, `nbits` is current network difficulty.

Difficulty encoding is throughly described [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty).

Hexadecimal representation like `0x1b3cc366` consists of two parts:

- `0x1b` -- number of bytes in a target
- `0x3cc366` -- target prefix

This means that valid hash should be less than `0x3cc366000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (it is exactly `0x1b` = 27 bytes long).

Floating point representation of difficulty shows how much current target is harder than the one used in the genesis block.

Satoshi decided to use `0x1d00ffff` as a difficulty for the genesis block, so the target was 
`0x00ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

And 1078.52975077 is how much current target is greater than the initial one:

```
$ echo 'ibase=16;FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 / 3CC366000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' | bc -l
1078.52975077482646448605
```